# How to send NSDate to soap web service - .net

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, soap

I have a little issue. I have to send NSDate as parameter to soap web method.

```
[WbMethod]
public void Method(DateTime date){...
```

From objective-c I send data like this:

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];

    ...
    NSString *soapMsg = 
        [NSString stringWithFormat:
         @"<?xml...
             "<date>%d</date>"
         ...
         "</soap:Body>"
         "</soap:Envelope>", date
         ];
```

I got error:

```
...<faultstring>Server was unable to read request. ---&gt; There is an error in XML document (1, 354). ---&gt; The string '93462576' is not a valid AllXsd value.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I have alse tried to change %d to %@ and then error is:

```
...faultstring>Server was unable to read request. ---&gt; There is an error in XML document (1, 371). ---&gt; The string '2012-01-26 14:27:45 +0000' is not a valid AllXsd value.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What date format your service expects? Timestamp, datetime, maybe some other custom "yyyMMddhhmm"?

Comment: What format should the date be in for the SOAP request?

Comment: DateTime no custom formats. month/day/year hour,min,sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it should be in format you mentioned, then

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh,mm,ss"];
NSString *yourDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[formatter release];
```

Comment: I have used this date format and it worked: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why are you doing %d as that represents an integer.
Are you trying to get the unix timestamp of your NSDate ? If so you can use [timeIntervalSince1970](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSince1970) or use `description` to get a string representation of your NSDate object.

Comment: I have tried this also and pass to service as '%f' and I get error:  The string '1327652581.522795' is not a valid AllXsd value. This is how I get date: NSTimeInterval date = [now timeIntervalSince1970];

Comment: Again %f is representing float and %d is representing integers. None of them actually convert an NSDate to a usable formate. If your SOAP service requires a yyyyMMddhhmm format, you can use NSDateFormatter as suggested by others.

Answer (score 1):

NSDateFormatter is what you are looking for